# How precedence works inside the append function in python

Tags: python

Im looking to know if someone can explain to me how the following piece of code results in the below output.

**CODE:**

```
board = []

for o in range(5):

    board.append(["O"]*5)

print board
```

**OUTPUT:**

[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]

To me I read "board.append(["O"]*5)" as:
append to the list board, a list containing the letter "O", and then do this 5 times therefore ending up with which is incorrect:

[['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O'], ['O']]

Can someone explain if there's some precedence happening here or why this is not the case as i cant seem to understand it?

Regards,
briarjr

Answer (score 0):

When creating arrays:

```
    ["O"]*5 => ["O","O","O","O","O"]
```

Because of this when you .append(["O"]*5) 5 times due to your loop, you are actually appending ["O","O","O","O","O"] 5 times.